# How can I delete an old entry in a table when inserting a new one that maches 3 conditions using VBA in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

So it's a bit tricky for me since I started learning this 3 days ago...

I have a table with 4 columns: Station name | Date | Program name | Status

When I insert a new record, it will match older ones - but the date will always be different.

I need a code to add to my code that will allow an automatic search of similar records by : Station Name + Program Name  - but only for those in the current month, and delete the old existing record before writing in the new one.

---

This is my current code connected to a button:

```
Sub OK()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Check if all data was filled

With Empt

  If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("D4").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please fill all fields"

 ' ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("E4").Value) = True Then
 'MsgBox "Please fill all fields"

  ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("F4").Value) = True Then
   MsgBox "Please fill all fields"

  ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("G4").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please fill all fields"

Else

'Insert data to table

Sheet1.Range("E4").Value = Now()
Sheet1.Range("D4:G4").Copy
Sheet1.Range("A10").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
MsgBox "All data have been copied!"
Sheet1.Range("D4:G4").ClearContents
'Sheet1.Range("E4").Value = "Auto Fill"

End If
End With

 'CHANGE COLOR OF CELLS

With colrng

NonEmp = Sheet1.Application.CountA(Range("D10:D100000"))

Set MyPlage = Range("D10:D10" & NonEmp)

For Each Cell In MyPlage

Select Case Cell.Value

Case Is = "Completed"
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43

Case Is = "Waiting"
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

Case Is = "Uploading"
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

Case Else
Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End Select
Next
End With

' Save records

   Sheet1.Range("A10:E50000").Validation.Delete
   ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

---

Can someone help please?

[image: Station Updating.png]

Comment: A few questions please? when you say insert a new row are you talking about this being done by your code above or an event based on a manual paste? Would you like it to replace the row or create a new one at the bottom after deleting the match?

Comment: Its a bit hard to follow not seeing the data but looking at the code what seems to happen is: 1) user enters new values in D4:G4. 2) When your macro runs it checks if all fields are entered. 3) If it is it always moves the data to the 10th row I guess that is the bottom?? 4) you then color format the results. Are you asking how to delete matching rows from row 4-9 for the last month?

Comment: Hi. thankks...  the 10th row is the first of the table and each new entry goes threre while the existing ones move down (I really dont know what in the code does that but I like it this way)

Comment: I dont know how to add a screenshot here... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub OK()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, lr As Long, inc As Range, ref As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Main")
    Set inc = ws.Range("D4:G4") 'Insert Data
    Set ref = ws.Range("A9")    'Station
    With ws
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        If inputIsValid(.Range("D4,F4,G4")) Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set ur = .Range(ref, "D" & lr)
            removePrev ur, .Range("D4"), .Range("F4")
            .Range("E4").Value = Now

            inc.Copy
            ref.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            inc.ClearContents
            With ref.Offset(1, 3)
                Select Case .Value2
                    Case "Completed":   .Interior.ColorIndex = 43
                    Case "Waiting":     .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Case "Uploading":   .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End Select
            End With
            .Range("D4").Activate
            ThisWorkbook.Save
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Function inputIsValid(ByRef inRng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim cel As Range, result As Boolean, invRng As Range
    result = True
    For Each cel In inRng
        If Len(cel) = 0 Then
            If invRng Is Nothing Then Set invRng = cel Else Set invRng = Union(invRng, cel)
            result = False
        End If
    Next
    If Not result Then
        invRng.Interior.Color = vbBlue
        MsgBox "Please enter values in blue cell(s)"
        invRng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    End If
    inputIsValid = result
End Function

Private Sub removePrev(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal sn As String, pn As String)
    Dim v As Range
    With rng
        Set v = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sn
        If v.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=xlFilterThisMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
            If v.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=pn
                If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
                    v.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

---

- It works on the following test file:

  [image]

.

Note: The last sub (showStatus) can be replaced with 3 Conditional Formatting Rules:

[image]

Comment: THanks, I'll give it a try now, and see if I can understad how to get it to work :)

Comment: Ok... so it has issues.....  keeps getting stuck on this line:    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, Date)

and if I cancel it then it gets stuck on this:  Set v = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)  - and then this -                     v.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.EntireRow.Delete

Any idea why?

Comment: Its either that I can replace existing or create a new entry... not both and cannot be connected to this month....   Im sorry for all the hassle :)

Comment: The issue is related to column B being formatted as Date (not as Text, or General) - Excel can only filter on dates if it "sees" them as dates. Can you check the type of formatting you have for all date values in column B: right-click one of the dates and select "Format Cells" - in the first Tab (Number") what format is selected? After you format all values as dates check your Regional Settings for Dates: Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Advanced -> Additional Settings -> Dates, but it's easier if you record the AutoFilter for that column and post back the format (similar "8/31/2014")

Comment: I changed it, but it didn't fix the bug.  However, I need it to show the time as well as the date - because some of the data is updated on an hourly base.  and it needs to be limited to the current month  - i.e. if there is similar data (pn + sn) from last month - than it shouldnt change it.

Comment: Well... it seems to be more tricky than I thought... it's a weekly show, so the updating must be limited to 4-7 days only

so within a given month - there will be 4 listings of the same program+station

Comment: Ok, so you'll need to delete all records with same pn + sn from last week, correct? I need to know the Number Format in column B: how does it display on screen, and when you record the AutoFilter: to record AutoFilter select your data (Column A to D, all rows) starting with the header row, then go to Data Tab and click "Filter". Now click Macros -> Start Recording, then click the Date drop-down, select one of this week's dates to filter by it. Stop Recording. Open VBA and go to Macro1 - post the date that appears on line with AutoFilter exactly as it appears between the quotes ("8/31/2014")

Comment: I need to overrite same PN + SN records of the same week - last week or last month will have the same record since they are weeky shows.

I just need to know  - per show+per channle+per week the last upload status.

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("$B$9:$B$24").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        ">20/08/2015 22:03", Operator:=xlAnd

Comment: I thought i did convert them into date... its just date+time.

Comment: I updated the 2nd sub (removePrev) to compare dates as strings. Try it now - the week (variable "dt") might need finer adjustments to include just last week

Comment: It's beyond me....  now it stops in :  ** v.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.EntireRow.Delete **

Comment: On a second try it gets stuck on ***  .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sn ***.... Im lost. the code also bugs out my other macros...  :(

Comment: Ok... so I isolated the problem, its the delete line, I added a question box to allow user to overwrite or add - but it will not delete still

Comment: What is the error message (error number and details)? I'm testing with a simple file and it works well, your workbook or sheet might be protected

Comment: Well it's not protected and the message is "no cells were found" while finding cells that are not related to the input data at all....   Im at a loss here....

Comment: I'd need to test with your file to be able to find the issue

Comment: Fine. How do I send it to you?

Comment: I updated the answer based on the file you sent - let me know if there are any other issues